# Sort by one column, but get offset by another

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with two columns:

```
|  ID  |  A  |
```

I want to sort by A, then get the 10 records after a given ID.   What would be the best way to handle this in Postgres?

To clarify, I want to sort by A, but do my pagination by the ID.  So if I had a table like:

```
1 | 'C'
2 | 'B'
3 | 'A'
4 | 'G'
5 | 'A'
6 | 'H'
```

So after sorting by A, I'd want the first three values after id=1, so:

```
1 | 'C'
4 | 'G'
6 | 'H'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordering of any column is purely dependant on the `order by`  clause and the terms "before" or "after" come into picture only when there's a pre-determined order. So, once the records are ordered by column "A", there's no guarantee that the id's will be ordered in the sequence `1,4,6`, unless you also specified that ordering of id.

So, if you

> want the first three values after id=1

It means there should be a way to determine the point where the id value has become 1 and all the rows beyond are to be considered. To ensure that you have to explicitly include id in the `order by`. A `COUNT` analytic function can come to our rescue to mark the point.

```
SELECT id,a
FROM ( SELECT t.*,COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 END) --the :id argument
         OVER( ORDER BY a,id) se 
       FROM t order by a,id --the rows are ordered first by a, then by id 
                            -- same as in the above count analytic function
     ) s
WHERE se = 1  limit 3; -- the argument 3 or 10 that you wish to pass
                       -- se = 1 won't change for other ids, it's a marker 
                       -- that id = n is reached
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c93e7e1db68683d769cd1fc4fc207abf)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * from MyTable where ID > givenId order by A) sub
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: `Top`  is not available in PostgresSQL. I'm not sure why would someone upvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `A` columns, so:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM t 
WHERE t.id > ANY (SELET id FROM t t2 WHERE t2.col = 'A')
ORDER BY col
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that this does not return any rows with `A` as the value.  It also works when the comparison value is not sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where "ID"=1 
order by "A" desc limit 2;
```

check :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5854b/3

for your query :

```
SELECT * from Table1 where "ID"=1 
    order by "A" desc limit 10;
```